# Can incrementing a pointer cause leaked memory?

Tags: c, pointers, memory-management

Does the following code contain a memory leak of the first three characters in the string?

```
char * str = (char*)malloc(21 * sizeof(char));
strcpy(str, "01234567890123456879");
str = str + 3;
free(str);
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Its worse than a *leak*, you are not supposed to call `free` with a pointer not returned from `malloc` (or `realloc`/`calloc`). You could get a leak, or a crash, or who knows what else... What you do is *undefined behavior*.

Comment: Just to clarify, the spec qualifies that as undefined behavior.

Comment: Monkeys fly out of your USB Port!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, It leaks.

`free` expects a pointer that was returned by `malloc/realloc/calloc`. Since, you have changed, it certainly leaks.

Comment: Its Undefined Behavior not a memory leak.

Comment: Passing incorrect pointer to `free` is UB. But the program still leaks?

Comment: I understand why the distinction is made on undefined behaviour. It might show up as a leak, but it is still undefined.

Comment: If you're lucky it will crash immediately, so I don't think you can say it *certainly* leaks. It's also not too hard to imagine a conforming implementation that manages to free the memory anyway (for example if it ignores the bottom two bits of the pointer for some weird reason, perhaps due to the way that aligned word-sized memory access works on the architecture). That particular implementation doesn't leak, so again I don't think you can say that it certainly leaks. All that's certain is that it isn't guaranteed not to leak.

Comment: 1. *Passing incorrect pointer to free is UB*. 2. *But the program still leaks?*, After `#1` the program is not a valid C program anymore, so speculating on behavior of `#2` does not make any sense at all.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to prove this out by testing, but I believe the answer to your question is that incrementing a pointer can cause undefined behaviour, although you are seeing a memory leak.

I am saying this, because nowhere in your example does it appear that you have preserved the original pointer to the allocated memory. It is possible free could do the wrong thing with the pointer pointing to somewhere other than the base address.

To be sure you would need to

1) Look at RAM in use on your system, with as little else running as possible

2) Run the program a few times, and

3) Then look at memory use again.

Then try all that again by altering your code as follows:

```
char * mem_ptr = (char*)malloc(21 * sizeof(char));
char * str = mem_ptr;

strcpy(str, "01234567890123456879");
str = str + 3;
free(mem_ptr);
```